# %trimmedwindow.label.eclipseSDK as text of title bar: Bug 373988

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm currently migration an Eclipse RCP application from 3.0 to 4.4. Due to the migration the text of the title bar is "%trimmedwindow.label.eclipseSDK" instead of the String it should be. I set the title like this:

```
public void preWindowOpen(IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer)
{
    ...
    myConfigurer = configurer;
    myProductName = configurer.getTitle();
}
...
public void perspectiveActivated(IWorkbenchPage page, IPerspectiveDescriptor perspective) 
{
    myConfigurer.setTitle(myProductName + " " +          perspective.getLabel());
}

public void perspectiveChanged(IWorkbenchPage page, IPerspectiveDescriptor perspective, String changeId) 
{
    myConfigurer.setTitle(myProductName + " " + perspective.getLabel());
}
...
```

The funny thing is: If I debug the code of `preWindowOpen(IWorkbenchConfigurer configurer)`, the text of the title bar which is contained in the variable `configurer` is correct, but after executing `myProductname = configurer.getTitle();` the value for the title bar text changes to "%trimmedwindow.label.eclipseSDK".

This **was** a bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=374116 which should be fixed for Eclipse 4.4, but I still get this strange behaviour. A workaround is easy: just set the text hardcoded, but this isn't very pretty. And I also don't understand why I get this bug although it should be fixed.

BTW: In Eclipse RCP 3.0 everything worked fine, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was fixed for Eclipse 4.5 (Mars). [Bug 374116 comment 8](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=374116#c8) shows that the last commit on this bug was in March 2015 to the master branch. That is after 4.4  was released in June 2014.

As you can see the file on the [master (Neon)](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/LegacyIDE.e4xmi#n5) and [4.5 (Mars)](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/LegacyIDE.e4xmi?h=R4_5_maintenance#n5) have the correct contents, but the [4.4 (Luna)](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/LegacyIDE.e4xmi?h=R4_4_maintenance#n5) does not have the fix.

I recommend if you are starting a new project you start with the latest (4.5.1 aka Mars.1) (as of Nov 2015)